# How to setup Flume for collecting logs in simple file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, flume, flume-ng

I am new to Flume. My requirement is to start a Flume agent from Java code with configuration like host, port etc. and when external service log their data it should be written in a simple text file e.g. server.log.

I don't want to use HDFS sink. What should be the configuration?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`File Roll Sink`](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#file-roll-sink), which stores the events in the local file system. You can use the given configuration example as a base for your configuration:

```
a1.channels = c1
a1.sinks = k1
a1.sinks.k1.type = file_roll
a1.sinks.k1.channel = c1
a1.sinks.k1.sink.directory = /var/log/flume
```

Now, you only have to choose a Flume source for putting events in the `c1` channel.

Comment: You'll still have to configure some kind of source though. Have a look at the log4j2 Flume agent for ideas.

Comment: I am using http-source, memory channel and file as sink. Everything is working fine now.